How to prevent orphan objects in argoCD apps?
In my configuration app folder I have 2 manifests: deployment.yaml and service.yaml. The argoCD app works fine, but at every update it creates a new replicaset, with a new pod and when the new pod is healthy, the old one dies. The problem is that the old replicaset stays and are never removed. How to proceed?ArgoCD dashboard view

The fact that there is a ReplicaSet history shown under a corresponding Deployment is not a problem but a feature:
kubectl explain deploy.spec.revisionHistoryLimit
GROUP:      apps
KIND:       Deployment
VERSION:    v1

FIELD: revisionHistoryLimit <integer>

DESCRIPTION:
    The number of old ReplicaSets to retain to allow rollback. This is a pointer
    to distinguish between explicit zero and not specified. Defaults to 10.

It is a generic Kubernetes concept, not specific to Argo CD.
